# Unanswered questions API does not work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions

The `/questions/unanswered` API returns the full list of questions (same as `/questions`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/questions` and `/questions/unanswered` are returning different sets of questions, which both are both functioning properly as far as I can tell.

Of the various functions in the API, those two have seen some of the most tweaking since we went into public beta; so it wouldn't surprise me if they were broken at some point.  They're `[status-norepo]` now though.

Comment: Yep, that is a no repro currently. `questions` gives me ~700K, `unanswered` gives me ~100K. Must've been fixed while tweaking other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you aware that *unanswered questions* in stackoverflow means **no upvoted answers**, right?

The query looks fine for me.

Comment: Either I don't understand the meaning of **no upvoted answers**, or there's something wrong. I am getting `"total": 683482` in the result, which is the same number SO prominently displays on the home page as total number of questions. Also, in the results list I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812, which does not have an accepted answer, but has multiple upvoted answers. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, the "total" field could be "bug", you might want to raise it in seperate thread. For questions 194812, let me take a look into the list.

Comment: @Franci, could you show me your json, or api url? I don't see 194812 in my unanswered results, but found in questions result.